# Why do I get a NameError when running code from Automate the Boring Stuff, Chapter 2

Tags: python, nameerror

This is a total newbie question for which I have searched the site.

I am running a really simple program from the book [Automate the Boring Stuff, Chapter 2](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter2/).

I keep getting this error:

> NameError: name 'name' is not defined

The first line of code is:

```
if name == 'Alice':
```

Why am I getting this `NameError` ?

Comment: You should define/create `name` _before_ using it.

Comment: Please share the code and error. Please check this link ,- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

In the [book](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter2/) you missed this comment above the code:  "*(Pretend name was assigned some value earlier.)*".  So you need to do that.  For example (assuming Python 3):

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice.')
```

By the way, next time you are searching for this kind of thing in a search engine, prefix the exception type with "python", for example "python NameError".

Comment: Thank you very much. I did see that comment (Pretend name was assigned some value earlier) but assumed that since there were another few iterations of this code with Alice that somewhere this would resolve. I was also surprised NameError was barely in the index. Thanks again.